# Kernel problems on Asus E403S

Tags: kernel, touchpad, asus

I have ubuntu 15.10 on Asus E403S with this xinput,

```
    (20:19:49)──> xinput                                     1 ↵ ──(ke,tammi13)─┘
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ ELAN1000:00 04F3:0401                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
        ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam                     id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
```

And linux-image (uname -r)

```
    4.2.0-23-generic
```

Problem is two finger scrolling is not working and the hibernate option is dimmed out thus i cannot choose that option.

After upgrading to kernel 4.3* and even 4.4*, two finger scrolling is working but new problems,

1. the mouse freeze at any moment and i have to hard boot the computer
2. Reboot is not completing, that is it plays the playmouth and then gets stuck in a blank screen and never reboots

Any solution to this?

Thanks.

Comment: Disabling bluetooth solved the touchpad issue and for the unending boot and reboot, the solution is found here http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=163126&start=20#p961212

Comment: Hi Jaws, please add an answer and accept it ... and remove solved from the title, the accepted answer is the indicator for a solved problem.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned on comments, disabling Bluetooth and adding this

```
blacklist dw_dmac
blacklist dw_dmac_core
```

to

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

solved all the issues for me. I got this from this link http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=163126&start=20#p961212